# How to zero-extend a number if it is valid, or X-extend it otherwise?

Tags: verilog

I have a 16-bit number which might be `x` (i.e. unknown).
I would like to zero-extend the number to 32 bits, but if the MSB is `x`, then I would like it to be `x`-extended instead of zero-extended. (This helps with my simulation.)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you are working with signed values, I think you will need a custom function for this. If you are working with signed values, the MSB will be X-extended on an assignment from a 16-bit value to a 32-bit value if the sign bit is X. However if the MSB (the sign bit) is a 1 then it will be 1-extended, which is most likely not what you want if you are working with unsigned values.

Here's a simple function to do this.

```
function [31:0] extend(input[15:0] in);
begin
   if (in[15] === 1'bX) begin
      extend = {16'hXXXX, in};
   end else begin
      extend = {16'h0000, in};
   end
end
endfunction
```

Example:

```
$display("%032b", extend(16'h0000));
$display("%032b", extend(16'hFFFF));
$display("%032b", extend(16'bX000_0000_0000_0000));
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000001111111111111111
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx000000000000000
```

Comment: You can also avoid the if/else and just say 'extend = { {16{in[15}}, in};'  Avoids unecessary control flow statements which I think is almost always a win in Verilog since it more closely models what you're actually building.

Comment: @BrianMagnuson That's a nice suggestion but I think the OP wanted to zero extend even if bit 15 was a 1.  What you have would extend with 1's in that case.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I suppose you could make the first part of the concatination {16{in[15] & 1'b1}}.  That's starting to get a bit obfuscated though.

Answer (score 2):

If your simulator is modern enough to support SystemVerilog syntax:

```
module tb;

reg [15:0] a;
reg [31:0] b;

initial begin
    $monitor("a='b%b b='b%b", a, b);
    #5 a= '1; extendo();
    #5 a= '0; extendo();
    #5 a= 'z; extendo();
end

task extendo;
    b[15:0] = a[15:0];
    b[31:16] = (a[15] === 1'bx) ? 'x : '0;
endtask

endmodule
```

Output:

```
a='bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx b='bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
a='b1111111111111111 b='b00000000000000001111111111111111
a='b0000000000000000 b='b00000000000000000000000000000000
a='bzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz b='b0000000000000000zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```